# ODE Solution for Canonical State Space form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, control-theory

Suppose I have a first order ODE

$$
X'(t) = A(t)X(t), \quad \quad X(t_0) = X_0
$$
where $X\in R^n$, and **time-dependent** $A(t)$ has a **[canonical state-space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-space_representation#Canonical_realizations)** form

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & & &\\
0 & 0 & 1 & &\\
 \vdots & \cdots  &  & &\\
a_1(t) & a_2(t) & a_3(t) & \cdots & a_n(t)
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I have two questions:

1. Could I express the solution as

$$
X(t) = X_0\,e^{\int^t_{t_0}A(s)ds}
$$
in this particular case? Does $A(t)$ commutes with its integral?

2. If no, how about if I say the coefficients $a_1(t),a_2(t)\cdots$ are selected such that $A(t)$ has $n$ identical real negative eigenvalue $r(t)$? If again no, what could be a condition of $A(t)$ such that it could?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For general $A(t)$ the solution is given by the [Magnus Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnus_expansion).

Important special cases are when $A(t), A(t')$ commute or when $A(t)$ is constant. Then the solutions are given by the [Matrix Exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential#Linear_differential_equation_systems)
\begin{align}
A(t)A(t') &= A(t')A(t) 
&&\implies
&&X(t_1) = \exp \left(\int_{t_0}^{t_1} A(t') \, dt' \right) X_0
\\
A(t) &= A_0 = \text{const} 
&&\implies
&&X(t_1) = \exp \left( A_0 (t_1-t_0) \right) X_0\,.
\end{align}

---

For your $A(t)$: in general it does not commute. Thus, you have to use the magnus series which will probably not help a lot.